# Multiple app installer or multiple launchables

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

I want to create an "app loader" (primary) application, which will fetch a license from a server -- this license in turn will determine the features available in two other (secondary) applications.

I'd like to know the best approach to this.  Should I:

1. just fetch the two secondary apks from the same server as the licensing info and attempt their installation from within the app loader code;
2. pack the secondary apks into the primary app apk.  Am I able to then install the secondary apks from within the 'parent' apk's resource/assets at runtime?
3. recreate the secondary applications as multiple activities within one parent app -- with multiple launchers?

I require advice on the individual scenarios' feasibility, a preference (with a reason why) and indeed which ones are actually possible.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I able to then install the secondary apks from within the 'parent' apk's resource/assets at runtime?

Not without copying those files to external storage. Since you cannot modify resources or assets at runtime, your "packed" "secondary" APKs will remain in the parent APK, for better or worse.

> I require advice on the individual scenarios' feasibility

All are feasible, within the constraints outlined above.

Comment: "All are feasible, within the contsraints outlined above" - I presume you mean for (1) and (2) to procure the files (from server or from within assets) and then store externally and then run. two questions regarding this - (i) can I store the files under the parent apps subdirectory structure on device (data/data...) (ii) will I run into permission problems on certain OSs (I only have 2.3 with no experience of what caveats are applied in later releases).

Comment: @CoastalB: "I presume you mean..." -- I meant the first paragraph of my answer. "can I store the files under the parent apps subdirectory structure on device (data/data...)" -- only if the file is `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` for the duration of the install process. The installer is a different process with no rights to normal files on internal storage. "will I run into permission problems on certain OSs" -- no, there is no particular permission required to `ACTION_VIEW` an APK file.

Comment: Sorry - I queried your first paragraph solely as I initially misunderstood "you cannot modify resources.." I didn't want to modify anything, just read out the apks, but I now see what you meant.  As you suggested, I will try extraction of secondary apks (set with M_W_R) to parent app's subdirectory and execute.  To be honest, I didn't think it would be that straightforward -- for some reason I assumed the native installer (for security purposes) would have some additional associated permissions.

Comment: @CoastalB: Since the user has to approve all installations, additional permissions are not necessary.